# Is there way to use QT Designer UI forms so you get direct access to the form widgets in your program?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

I'm having trouble finding a way to use multiple UI forms in one program so that I get direct access to the widgets in the forms.  Direct access would make it much easier to implement my backend and connect it the frontend form files.  As it is now I have to use public modification methods to change widgets in the forms and also intermediate signals and slots to communicate between the form's widgets and the code in my backend class.  It would be much easier to just change the widgets directly and connect them directly to slots in my backend class.  Can something like this even be done?
Thanks

Comment: If your form widgets are accessed using private `ui` field, you can just expose that field with a public getter and just use it directly from other classes. It would be good to see some of your code demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Sorry haven't responded timely thanks for the help.  I found a way to do (kinda a hack) and it works not so elegant but good enough.